# How to insert/update data in database

Tags: database

I want to save data in a mysql table database using drupal 7 (costume module), but my question is that depends if the value exists I have to use the UPDATE command and if not INSERT command but I don't know how to write this code with the db api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [db_merge](https://www.drupal.org/node/310085)

> In the general sense, a **Merge query is a combination of an Insert
>   query and an Update query**. If a given condition is met, such as a row
>   with a given primary key already existing, then an Update query is
>   run. If not, an Insert query is run.

Thus, **db_merge** adds it, if it doesn't exist yet. OR updates it, if it already exists.

> ```
> db_merge('example')
>   ->key(array('name' => $name))
>   ->fields(array(
>       'field1' => $value1,
>       'field2' => $value2,
>   ))
>   ->execute();
> ```
>
> <sup>by: dzutaro, tlyngej, stewart.adam, AndreyMaximov</sup>